# Puma failing because request headers are `nil`, but they are present in `env`

Tags: ruby, sinatra, puma

Two applications, one using Puma 4.3.4 and one using Puma 5.6.4, have both started failing with the same error:

```
Read error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass>
```

Puma 5.6.4 gives no backtrace, but 4.3.4 indicates the problem is in `/usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.3.4/lib/puma/server.rb:759` which is where Puma calls `headers.each`.

I’ve dropped into Pry here, and indeed `headers` is `nil`, but I can’t figure out why. This was all working quite happily earlier today!

If I inspect `env` I can see the request headers as expected, `HTTP_HOST`, `HTTP_COOKIE` and so on. So why is Puma failing to do whatever manipulation it normally does in preparation for `handle_request`?

These apps are part of a docker-compose setup which includes a proxy, but calling directly to the applications from within their own container gives the same problem, so it’s not the proxy stripping the headers (and anyway, they would be missing from `env` if so).

Upgrading Puma 4.3.4 to 5.6.4 doesn’t fix things, which also makes sense because the 5.6.4 app is broken too, and I assume it’s the same problem although without a backtrace I’m not sure how to verify that.

These are Sinatra apps, but I’m not sure that’s relevant – the request doesn’t seem to have reached that point in the stack when the error happens.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the `sentry-ruby` Rack middleware. I will post a full answer when I fix it...

Answer (score 0):

So this was in fact a bug in a custom middleware: when it failed under certain circumstances it returned `nil` rather than raising an exception.

This meant that none of the usual Sinatra or Sentry error-handling was triggered, and in turn they passed the empty result back up to Puma, which then choked as above.

The key thing was to make sure the middleware raised an exception under all circumstances where it cannot give a response!